# Font-face flickering when new css files are dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

I am using the Google Webfont Loader to get my webfonts loaded with a callback and it is working fine.

Although, when a couple of components: Google +1 button, Twitter Search Widget and the Add This button is loaded, they add a new stylesheet to the DOM and makes the browser render the site again. This is causing the font-face to disappear and then show for each new stylesheet added to the dom.

I could hide the font entirely until the components are loaded but they tend to be pretty slow so that would leave me with a pretty bad user experience. About 1 sec of a headline-less site.

Andy tips on how to force font-face to not redraw or how to block dynamically loaded CSS from within Google, Twitter and FBs embed scripts?

Update: Demo here http://kristoferforsell.com/dev/fontexample/

Comment: Do you have an example? Can you narrow down which of the sharing components is causing the flicker, as in my experience they shouldn't have any impact on the page as a whole.

Comment: Sure, this is a quick example on the flickering. This one flickers once because of the regular FOST first and then once more when the stylesheet from Add This kicks in. The second flash/glitch goes for every appended stylesheet. If I add the Twitter widget there will be another flash or glitch. http://kristoferforsell.com/dev/fontexample/

Comment: I'm only seeing the AddThis buttons very infrequently, which seems to point to there being an issue there - are you sure that the JS that is loading them is all correct?

Comment: I first load the webfont with Google Webfont Loader, on the callback I load the add this and it should magically appear. This is where the font-face flickers, I am getting this in Chrome, FF and Safari. It is easier to spot if you do refresh the browser window a few times.

Answer (score 14):

This is currently an inherent issue with browsers and the @font-face property. The blink occurs when the font is loaded and the page updates to reflect the font. If you wish to remove the "blink" entirely, the only sure fire way is to include the font as a data URI in the style sheet. Of course, using the standard "safe" fonts will also remove the blink.

Data URIs allow you to actually embed the code for the font in the stylesheet so there's no blink when the page refreshes to show the desired font. Using data URIs, will obviously increase the file size (kb) of any style sheet.

An online converter to get base64 code can be found [here](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)

Usage for @font-face would be like so.....

```
 @font-face {
font-family: "My Font";
src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,[   the base64 code here   ]");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest a simple and dirty trick I have used myself to solve issues like this. If you implement this, from the user's side the effect will be that the entire page will load at once (with the correct Web Fonts), but after a delay. Once loaded, nothing will flicker or change.
Wrap your entire page contents in a div and set its visibility to hidden. Then use js to turn on the visibility once the **whole page** (stylesheets and all) is loaded.
Here's the code:

```
<head>
<script>
function show()
{document.getElementById('wrapper').style.visibility='visible';}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="show()">
<div id="wrapper">
...your entire page contents...
</div>
</body>
```

The `onload` ensures that the visibility is switched on only after the entire body has loaded. Although I haven't used Web Fonts, I use this trick to fade in the entire contents of [this website](http://www.iiserk.net/~abhra) with no changing or updating afterwards. But yes, there will be a delay before the entire page comes into view.

**EDIT:** I added Google Web Fonts to the site I linked. Still works fine. No font-face flickering.

Comment: Ah yes that would work and hopefully it will help a bunch of people with the same problem ending up here. For my case that won't really work though since this would leave me with a blank page for too long, my load sequence is like following to limit the loadtime. Load webfonts -> Init site since dom and fonts are ready -> Load third party scripts Eg. Twitter Search widget (since it is super slow) and this is where I get the flickering. Any other way would leave the user with a blank page for 1-2 secs wich is a bit too much. But still, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if it would fix your issue but you could use css to set the visibility of the elements to hidden until the **font** is loaded. Google's API provides `wf-loading` and `wf-active` classes which are added to the body to address this issue.

I always set up a separate stylesheet just for the @font-face rule, and within that put in the following rules, where `replace` is the class of the element that's being replaced, for you that would just be the `p` tag.

`.wf-loading .replace { visibility: hidden;}`

Yours would be

`.wf-loading p { visibility: hidden;}`

Then as soon as the webfont is loaded, JS puts the wf-active class on the body, and your text shows up. Let me know how that goes and if you have any issues then just drop me a line. It might also be worth doing some searching for "flash of unstyled content" or "flash of unstyled text" as this is a well known and well documented bug.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem we're having is initially the fonts are loaded and displayed properly without too much of a FOUC. After the fonts are initialized the rest of the 'social' js is being loaded (async), these come with their own css. Once that css gets loaded, the webfonts get rendered, which results in a couple of flickers at the rate of one per css file. We have been thinking about loading that social js blocking upfront, but that will halt the rendering of the DOM for far too long. So the real question: how can we avoid re-rendering of the font when new css gets loaded.

Comment: May be this is easier to reduce the flickering by reduce the number of CSS file?

Comment: We're using just one CSS file, but the third party javascripts load in their own css-es as well, which causes the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, as I've not tested it:
Could you create another html page with only those social networking buttons, and then load that into an iframe? Then only set the src to the iframe once the document is fully loaded, so it doesn't hold anything up.

In html:

```
<iframe id="socialMedia"></iframe>
```

In script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#socialMedia').src = "http://mysite.com/mysocialmediastrip.html";
});
```

Where mysocialmediastrip.html contains all the social media buttons. Setting the src will cause that iframe to reload and pull in that content, but IIRC, the rest of the page will be left alone -- all of the button rendering will have been done in mysocialmediastrip.html, not in your main page.

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand what you are saying about the delay process, waiting while window loads before you actually show your goods. Abhranil provided a good solution but you can take his solution further.  You can use jQuery's ajax to load your specific page content that's using the special font type.  Why?  because ajax comes with a special function called [beforeSend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Within the beforeSend function(), you can load a very cool gift animation that will display on your screen, before your main content is ready to viewed.

Use that moment to show some creativity towards your audience, before the main event!

Answer (score 0):

The best and most simple answer is adding `font-display: block` when specifying a font face

```
@font-face {
   font-display: block; /* Fix flickering */
}
```

You should also preload the font in the html file

```
<head>
  <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/path_to_your_font.ttf">
  <-- repeat for all typeface -->
</head>
```